# how can i make number with or without +91 as same and return distinct number

Tags: mysql, sql

i am currently working on sms message App so the number, messages ,id storing in a database, currently the numbers are storing in the database as +91xxxxxxxxxx and without +91 as xxxxxxxxxx

```
          number    message
         -------   ---------
1   +917905521776   message   //message received
2   7905521776      mess      //message sended
```

i am using sql command as

```
select distinct(number),message from table_name where substr(number,-10,10)=substr(number,-10,10) group by number;
```

the output i am getting is same as above table

**EDITED:**

i want the out as

```
    1   7905521776      mess      //message sended
                        message
```

Comment: To start with: `DISTINCT` is not a function. `select distinct(number), message` is the same as `select distinct number, message` getting distinct rows, i.e. no duplicate number/message pairs.

Comment: Please show your expected output. You want one result row instead of two, correct? What shall it contain?

Comment: If a given number has more than one message associated with it, then which messages do you want to display, and how do you want to display them?

Comment: You tagged `DISTINCT ON`. This is a function in PostgreSQL and not available in MySQL. You are using `DISTINCT` (without `ON`) in your query instead, which is different. And superfluous, because rows are already distinct because of your `GROUP BY` clause. I'm removing the wrong tag.

Comment: please see my question i have edited

Comment: `replace(number,'+91','')`?  though I freely admit I don't really understand the question.